# Why git add README fails on my Ubuntu?

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am learing git today. And I followed [this book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository).
It asks me to do three operations:

1. `git add *.c # my file name`
2. `git add README`
3. `git commit -m 'initial project version'`

I did 1 and 3 ssuccessfully, but when I did 2, my 
terminal says

`pathspec 'README' did not match any files`.

Why? How to fix it? I am using Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Do you have a README file with which to add? If not, `touch README` might do the trick.

Comment: Nope, now I added it and it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a `README` file before you can add it to be tracked by git.  Try creating a `README` file either using your text editor of choice, or perhaps creating a dummy file by using `touch README`.  Then your `git add README` should succeed.